# Display the first word of a full name in Retool?

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, retool

I have a prebuilt column of names in my SQL table. The first name and surname are on the same column. I want to only display the first name in Retool. How do I separate out the first name only from a full name in Retool using JavaScript?

Example "John Smith" should only display "John"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Table component Inspector (the right-hand panel), there is a section to edit the column settings. Click on your `full_name` column to show the settings for that column, and you will see an input for the **Mapped Value**. This setting allows you to alter the displayed value in the table. Assuming your column contains a first and last name, separated by a space character, like this:

```
full_name
------------------
Ursula User
Barry Bore
Eva Noyce
Elizabeth Meets
```

Then you can use a short Javascript expression to split the value on the space character and display only the first value.

```
{{ self.split(' ')[0] }}
```

In this example, everything inside the `{{ }}` evaluates to Javascript and the `self` variable represents the value for each cell in the column.

Here's a screenshot of the table before adding the **Mapped Value**:
[image: Table before adding mapped value]

And here's a screenshot of the table after adding the **Mapped value**:

[image: Table with the full_name column mapped to just use the first name]

There are, of course, many ways to do this in Retool, depending on your preference. You can also split a string in SQL. For example, in PostgreSQL, there is a function called `split_part()` which allows you to split string based on a delimiter similar to the Javascript split function used above. Using this would allow you to skip the Javascript altogether and do your string manipulation in SQL:

```
select 
  split_part(full_name, ' ', 1) as first_name
from 
  users
```

Here's an example of this method in action:
[image: Using SQL to split a string]

Comment: Is there a good resource or cheat sheet you can advise that lists simple javascript expressions like the one you referenced {{ self.split(' ')[0] }}

Simple scripts to help re-word data?

Like if i wanted to convert all "B"'s into "Beach" or do simple things like that. I hate writing a post for something that is probably relatively simple to someone with reasonable JS skills.

Comment: Hey @Exhausted - sure thing! My primary reference for Javascript knowledge is MDN by Mozilla. Here are two pages you will find useful for string manipulation: 
1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Useful_string_methods

The intermediate step would be to use Lodash (a commonly-used Javascript library that comes included in Retool): https://lodash.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JavaScript you can do

```
function first_name(full_name) {
    return full_name.split(" ")[0];
}
```